# What does it mean that a Listener can be replaced with lambda?

Tags: android, lambda, android-alertdialog

I have implemented an `AlertDialog` with normal negative and positive button click listeners.

When I called `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` it was showing me a suggestion saying: `Anonymous new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() can be replaced with lambda`. I know it's not an error or something big but what exactly is this suggestion and what can I do about it?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButton("Text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

`Android Studio V1.2.1.1
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
 minSdkVersion 14
 targetSdkVersion 22`

Comment: Could you add some part of your code using this ?

Comment: against which version of android are you compiling ?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It means that you can shorten up your code.

An example of `onClickListener()` **without** lambda:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

can be rewritten **with** lambda:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
    // do something here
});
```

It's the same code. This is useful when using a lot of listeners or when writing code without an IDE.
For more info, check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Just remember that lambda is Java 8 feature which is not supported in android. If you like this feature use retrolambda - https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Comment: @rwojcik Lambda is supported in Android

Comment: @Strider What happened if I want to add another method inside of listener? How can I write it?

Comment: Android N started to support Java 8, so `Lambda` is officially supported now.

Comment: And you don't need to import "android.view.View" or "android.view.View.OnClickListener" for click Listeners.

Comment: Note that the usage of lambda functions not only allows for shortening code and making code more elegant; it also produces [more efficient bytecode](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-8-Lambdas-A-Peek-Under-the-Hood).

Comment: Which is fast??  Lamda or Simple interface . or can anyone explain what is the difference between them besides shortening the code. is it worth to replace all interfaces by lamda in fully developed app ???

Comment: @PrinkalKumar You should ask a new question for that rather than hope it gets answered in the comments of this one.

Comment: So what is actually going on? Does a lamda sport a hidden anonymous class underneath like without, or is it just the function pointer and the anonymous class can be discarded? It would seem a class is not the same parameter type as a function pointer...?

Answer (score 7):

Its as simple as this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(view -> username = textView.getText());
```

Comment: @M Hornbacher Yes

Answer (score 5):

To replace the classic new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() implementation with lambda expression is enough with the following

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("resourceId", ((DialogInterface dialog, int which) -> {
      // do something here
 }));
```

It´s just taking the onClick event parameters.