# What is the use of Retrolambda?

Tags: java, android, retrolambda

What is the use of Retrolambda?
Where do we use the Retrolambda framework?

Comment: It's to be able to use Java 8's lambda functionality into Android. You'd use it if you want to use lamdbas

Comment: what is backport ?

Comment: I've edited my comment

Comment: I can use in android app?

Comment: Yes you can! Try it

Comment: where we use retrolambda in our app?

Comment: Wherever you want to use lamdbas

Comment: give me any type of example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30752800/833647

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In earlier versions of Android, Java 8 was not supported. Retrolambda provides a way to use "lambda expressions" on Java versions below 8.

Common examples of lambdas in Android are for click listeners

```
button.onClick(v -> Log.i("hello", "lambdas"));
```

However, as of Android Studio 2.4 Preview 4 and later, it

> supports all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language features

"Lambdas" are available on all SDK versions

Android studio provides tooling to migrate from Retrolambda as it is no longer necessary.

[Android Java 8 Support](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html)

Also, worth mentioning

> Retrolambda lacks support for third party libraries that use Java 8 language features.

Comment: My point is that it isn't necessary to use it anymore.  OP probably found some old tutorials that mention it

Comment: It is necessary for everybody who wants to use lambdas and not develop with preview builds of AS. Anyway suggesting someone should use B where the question is asking what A is used for probably belongs in a comment

Comment: Yeah, I rephrased. Thanks for the typo fixes

Answer (score 3):

Retrolambda is a library which allows to use Java 8 lambda expressions, method references and try-with-resources statements on Java 7, 6 or 5.

The Gradle Retrolambda Plug-in allows to integrate Retrolambda into a Gradle based build. This allows for example to use these constructs in an Android application, as standard Android development currently does not yet support Java 8.

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

textView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> System.out.println("Long Click"));

you can use this link :
 https://mayojava.github.io/android/java/using-java8-lambda-expressions-in-android

Comment: That link is outdated as Java 8 features are in the Android Studio canary channel. Without Jack compiler