# Is this possible to dynamically assign onClick functions to buttons?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 buttons and I'm wondering is this possible to dynamically assign them onClick methods. Three of these buttons should have 'lose()' method and one of them should have 'win()' method. Every turn 'win()' method will be assigned to new button. The winning button has tag 'winner' and every new turn as like above tag is assigned to new button. What's the best sollution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with lambda expressions! Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752547/listener-can-be-replaced-with-lambda) and see if it helps

Comment: It is simple OnClickListener, lambda expressions has nothing to this case.

Comment: Well.. yeah, but with lambda the code is cleaner and readable, so I thought it would be better in this case